# Event listener for when a file has finished streaming to AWS S3 upload api?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipe, filestream

I am creating a file backup between Google Drive and AWS S3. Where I create a Readable stream promise by downloading the file using the Google Get API and Pipping the data to AWS S3.
As I have many files, each promise is added to a queue and only new promises enter when it resolves.

I'm struggling to only resolve the promise when the file has completed upload to AWS S3, rather than when the file has downloaded?

I thought using `.on('finish', () => {resolve()})` should do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code sample:

```
// download stream of NON gdocs files and pipe to destination
const getGFileContent = async (fileObj) => {  
  let fileExt = fileObj.path.join('/').concat('/',fileObj.name)

  return drive.files.get({fileId: fileObj.id, mimeType: fileObj.mimeType, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'})
    .then(res => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.data
          .pipe(uploadS3(fileExt))
          .on('end', () => {console.log(`Done downloading file: ${fileExt}`)})
          .on('finish', () => {resolve(console.log(`File Backup Complete: ${fileExt}`))})
          .on('error', err => {reject(console.error(`Error downloading file: ${err}`))})
      })

// upload a file to AWS S3 by passing the file stream from getGFileContent into the 'body' parameter of the upload
const uploadS3 = (filePath) => {
  let pass = new stream.PassThrough()
  let params = {
    Bucket: awsBucketName, // bucket-name
    Key: filePath, // file will be saved as bucket-name/[uniquekey.csv]
    Body: pass  // file data passed through stream
  } 
  new aws.S3().upload(params).promise()
    .then(() => console.log(`Successfully uploaded to S3: ${filePath}`))
    .catch( err => console.log(`Error, unable to upload to S3: ${err}`))
  return pass
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to make `uploadS3` function `async` and `await` for the upload to finish, before returning the passThrough stream. **But this wouldn't work**. It would then return a Promise and the .pipe() accepts only a stream object.

**Instead of that**, you could refactor your code so that `getGFileContent` would return a readable stream promise.

Then, make `uploadS3` accept a readable stream as a parameter and return an s3 upload promise.

To wrap it up, add an async `backupFile` function, which will `await` for both GDrive steam and upload promises to be resolved before continuing. This will also keep the functions tidy and clean, each having its own single responsibility.

**Example code:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '----',
    secretAccessKey: '----',
});

const backupFile = async (file) => {
    const fileStream = await getGFileStream(file);
    try {
        await uploadStreamToS3(fileStream);
        console.log(`S3 Backup of ${fileStream.path} completed`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`error during file upload ${err}`);
    }
}

const getGFileStream = async (fileObj) => {
    // TODO: logic to find and get the file. Returns a readableStream promise 
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./largeFile.zip');
    console.log('File ${...} read from Google Drive');
    return fileStream;
}

const uploadStreamToS3 = (fileStream) => {
    const params = {Bucket: 'test-bucket', Key: 'key', Body: fileStream}
    console.log(`Starting to upload ${fileStream.path} to S3`);
    return s3.upload(params).promise();
}

backupFile({id: 'mockTestFile'});
```